# Do JBoss Seam applications have to be packages in an EAR?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, seam

Is it possible to package up a Seam application as a WAR file? I am trying to deploy a current  Seam application that was running in JBoss  to JBoss 6. It is packaged as a WAR file, but every example included with the Seam download seem to be packaged in an EAR with the Seam jar and application code, both deployed as EJBs

Comment: You can use an war file if you want. Which Seam version ??? Some exception thrown ??

Comment: Yes, you could easily create an application using seam-gen which uses java beans as components instead of ejbs. So you could run in tomcat as well as in jboss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sharing the error message at deployment would be helpful.

Was the web application (file.war) referencing services not in the file.war?

Most projects are deployed as an ear because the ejb modules are packaged separately (see below application.xml).  Take a look at the application.xml back on the original pre JBoss 6 server that it was running on.  It likely it had other modules besides the war file.

```
<application xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_5.xsd"
version="5">
  <display-name>Seam Registration</display-name>
  <module>
    <web>
    <web-uri>jboss-seam-registration.war</web-uri>Chapter 1. Seam
    Tutorial 14 
    <context-root>/seam-registration</context-root></web>
  </module>
  <module>
    <ejb>jboss-seam-registration.jar</ejb>
  </module>
  <module>
    <ejb>jboss-seam.jar</ejb>
  </module>
  <module>
    <java>jboss-el.jar</java>
  </module>
</application>
```